# map_err for Option<T>

Tags: error-handling, rust

So `Result<T, E>` has a pretty neat method `map_err` that allows to handle errors in a functional way:

```
use std::io::Result;
use std::error::Error;
use std::string::ToString;
use std::io;

fn init() -> Result<u32> { Ok(42) }

fn do_work(_data: u32) -> Result<()> { Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "IO Error!")) }

fn handle_error<E: Error + ToString>(error: E, message: &str) -> E {
    eprintln!("{}: {}", message, error.to_string());
    error
}

fn main() {
    let _ = init()
        .map_err(|e| handle_error(e, "Init error"))
        .and_then(do_work)
        .map_err(|e| handle_error(e, "Work error")); // "Work error: IO error"
}
```

It would be cool to have the same functional style for handling `Option<T>::None`:

```
use std::io::Result;
use std::error::Error;
use std::string::ToString;
use std::io;

fn init_opt() -> Option<u32> { Some(42) }

fn do_work_opt(_data: u32) -> Option<()> { None }

fn handle_none(message: &str) {
    eprintln!("{}", message);
}

fn main() {
    let _ = init_opt()
        .map_none(|| handle_none("Init error"))
        .and_then(do_work_opt)
        .map_none(|| handle_none("Work error")); // "Work error"
}
```

But I don't see any suitable replacement for this method in [documentation of `Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html)

It can be done with a custom trait like that

```
trait MapNone {
    fn map_none(self, op: impl FnOnce() -> ()) -> Self;
}

impl<T> MapNone for Option<T> {
    fn map_none(self, op: impl FnOnce() -> ()) -> Self {
        if self.is_none() { op(); } 
        self
    }
}
```

But I'm sure I'm missing something and there is some pretty way of doing the same via standard library.

[Full Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0264512f4ab49b772447b86c44827f2d)

Comment: A function that returns the unit type is not very useful in a functional style because it is required to operate by side effect. `Option` has [`or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.or_else) and [`unwrap_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else) that operate on `None`, but in a (IMHO) more useful way.

Comment: Well I didn't mean exactly functional idioms without side effects, but a "chain" handling of data

Comment: Using just the stdlib `.map_none(|| {….})` can be expressed as `or_else(|| {...; None})`. I'm not sure if that answers your question, i.e. whether it's pretty enough.

Comment: It answers in way of letting me know that there is no as convenient way as I already considered. Thanks on that

Comment: @user4815162342 post an answer please, if you want to be accepted

Comment: Thanks; I'm fine with the answer that got posted in the meantime getting accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `Option::or_else` exists that is a generalized form of what you propose. Rather than requiring it's function to return the unit type, it returns an `Option`, so simply have it return `None` to simulate your use case.

```
fn main() {
    let _ = init_opt()
        .or_else(|| {handle_none("Init error"); None})
        .and_then(do_work_opt)
        .or_else(|| {handle_none("Work error"); None}); // "Work error"
}
```

One can of course also now return `Some(x)` instead to branch differently.

Finally, `or_else` and `and_then` can also be combined with `map_or_else`:

```
fn main() {
    let _ = init_opt()
      .map_or_else(|| {handle_none("Init error"); None}, do_work_opt)
      .or_else(|| {handle_none("Work error"); None}); // "Work error"
}
```

This code should do the same as the above; `map_or_else` branches depending on whether the option be `None` or contain a value.